# run shell command when i save in sublime-text

Tags: sublime-text

i'm coding with html and each time i have to save the file and run the command line

```
$ google-chrome fileLoacation.html
```

Can i make subl do this automatically ?

Answer (score 3):

Specify a build system for HTML:

```
{
    "cmd": ["google-chrome", "$file"],
    "selector": "text.html"
}
```

and install the [SublimeOnSaveBuild](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeOnSaveBuild) package.